# Was Gus planning to kill Walt from the start?

Tags: breaking-bad

Obviously, when Walt shot two of Gus' trustworthy men in *Breaking Bad*, Gus wanted to kill Walt and have Gale replace him after learning his formula.

However, around the time Gus offers Walt '3 million dollars for 3 months of your time', did Gus plan to continue doing business with Walt after these 3 months, or was Walt just a disposable source of money? At this time, Walt wasn't seen as much of a threat (he wasn't as much of a liability as is in series 4).

So, is there any evidence to suggest that Gus planned to kill Walt (or not) from the start?

Comment: We know no one is secure no matter how he behaves towards you. Walt had come to his house to try to kill, had asked Mike to help kill him. His vengeance might have been reserved for the people who killed his lover or maybe it is enough to disobey him. I doubt any life insurer would give Walt an affordable policy. It would be interesting to know the back story of Victor, to find out just how close they had been, how much a surprise Frings actions were to him at the end -- who knows, maybe they had even been lovers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think Gus' initial plan was to sweeten the deal enough for Walt to become his chemist.

While extremely distrustful of him to begin with because of Jesse, Gus takes a risk and accepts Walt into his trade and even gives him the lab at the behest of Gale encouraging Gus that purity means more money.

Assuming everything went smoothly and certain events didn't occur, it is plausible that even *after* learning Walt's connection to Hank that it would still be beneficial to Gus to keep him on as long as he survived due to the extra money Gus could make and the monetary incentive for Walt.

Judging by the series as a whole, Gus only intended death for Walt *after* he ran over his dealers, breaking the peace to save Jesse's life, who was still considered a lowly *junkie* by Gus.

Comment: These actions very much portrayed Walt as a dog without a leash (from Gus' perspective as Walt's boss). Until then, Walt seemed a civilized and educated man, and his "bad manners" could have been attributed to hanging around with Jesse (which, as far as Gus could have known then, could have been a necessary evil that Walt suffered to become an established meth cook). Walt refusing to let go of Jesse could then also be construed as well-meaning loyalty, and is not directly indicative of Walt's bad character. Killing the dealers does prove that Walt does not respect the chain of command.

Answer (score 5):

Remember when Jesse was talking about how unfair the deal was at the lab on season 3 episode 8. He says in the middle of a a sentence,

> and like what happens at the end of the three months?

the Walt looks up for second looking concerned. Why would Gus just give up money after three months. You don't stop working for Gus, you work until you are killed by him.

Comment: It's also possible Gus figured after 3 months he would have gathered enough data on Walt's process to apply the technique to any chemist he finds.

Comment: That doesn't answer whether Gus was intent on killing Walt though. It only clarifies that Gus would kill Walt _if he stopped cooking_.

Answer (score 0):

No, Gus was not beacuse if he did, he wouldn't have said "Do you want to stay a year?"

Comment: Which episode is that quote from?

Comment: While I do believe Gus was not intent on killing Walt, the justification in this answer is flawed by blindly assuming Gus must be speaking the truth.

Comment: @Flater: Wait -- people lie in Breaking Bad? Kids watch that show...